# How can I use iptables to block certain processes from accessing the network?

Tags: networking, centos, iptables, access-control

I can set the processes to run under special uid's and use the technique from this [SF answer](https://serverfault.com/a/376569/140016):

```
 -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 400 -j DROP
```

...But are there any other ways to blacklist based on the PID or its parent's PID without setting up new user accounts?

Relevant links:

- [Blocking outgoing connects with iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27954/24379)

EDIT:

A possible duplicate of [Block network access of a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/block-network-access-of-a-process)

EDIT #2:

`unshare -n` doesn't work on CentOS/RHEL 6.5, since the kernel is compiled without `CONFIG_NET_NS=Y`.